# Facebook OAuth 2.0 PHP logout link doesn't logout on my site but it does on facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, logout

Okay as the title reads I've been trying to get Facebook's OAuth working on my localhost/, I've been struggling with various problems but I just don't know what's up with my latest problem, which is that the page loads, and if the user is logged in, it show's the logout URL and the UID like it should, and when I click the logout link it does log the user out from Facebook, but on redirect or reload the UID still appears and so does the logout link. Long story short, I can't seem to make my site that's running in my localhost log me out of Facebook AND on my site! Any thoughts would be a tremendous help. Here is my code

```
<?php

session_start();
// store session data

include "src/facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(Array(
    "appId" => "xxx",
    "secret" => "xxx"
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

echo "UID: " . $user . "<br/>";

    // THIS WAS MY FIRST TRY WHICH DIDNT SUCCEED
// if ($user) {
//  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
//  echo "<a href='" . $logoutUrl . "'>Logout</a>";
// } else {
//  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
//  echo "<a href='" . $loginUrl . "'>Login</a>";
// }

// WITH THE ABOVE CODE I GET:

// An error occurred with PHP-SDK. Please try again later.
// API Error Code: 191
// API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
// Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

    // THIS WAS MY SECOND TRY AFTER SEARCHING FOR INFO, 
    // ALL I DID WAS MANUALLY ADD THE
    // REDIRECT URI AND ADDED ? , THE REASON IS IF I DIDN'T ADD IT,
    // IT WOULD GIVE ME AN CSRF ERROR
    // STATING THAT THE STATE VALUE IS NOT CORRECT, I SEARCHED FOR THE SOLUTION
    // FOR THAT PROBLEM WITH NO LUCK SO I TRIED THIS

if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    echo "<a href='" . $logoutUrl . "'>Logout</a>";
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(Array(
        "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost/php-sdk/index.php?"
    ));
    echo "<a href='" . $loginUrl . "'>Login</a>";
}

// WITH THE ABOVE CODE I NOW GET A UID AND THE LOGOUT URL DOES APPEAR, BUT ONCE I CLICK IT
// THE USER IS LOGGED OUT LIKE HE SHOULD BUT THEN ON REDIRECT OR RELOAD THE UID STILL 
// APPEARS AND SO DOES THE LOGOUT LINK, EVEN THOUGH THE USER IS NOT LOGGED IN!!

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of facebook sdk store's the [user id](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php#L43) in your PHP session, and the logout process that takes place on the facebook's server can't clear that for you. You can see what's saved in session by checking the output of `var_dump($_SESSION);`

To detect if the uid stored in your session still logged in you could try using the SDK object to fetch something from the graph api, like (`$facebook->api('/me')`) and catch exceptions, and clear the session if they occur.

One other solution could be to add a `next` to the `getLogoutUrl()` call (just like in the `getLoginUrl()`) and when facebook sends the user back to that url, you clear the session variables. The default facebook implementation has [destroySession](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L1187) on the `BaseFacebook` class (for some reason not listed in offical sdk docs).

Comment: thanks for your reply, I sort of figured that out yesterday, and I'm going to implement your seccond solution about adding the redirect_uri on logout and destroying the session variables. It was kinda of obviose, thanks again for your reply!